# How to use NodeList to display random pictures?

Tags: javascript, random, nodelist

I have a problem that I need help with. I have been working on this for about half a day already. I am a new software developer still in school.

I have been trying to generate a random number to use as an index into the `imageTabsList` node list then using the `getAttribute()` method to get the `longdesc` attribute’s value from my HTML file that has the image path source written to the `longdesc` attribute below my for loop. So every time I reload the page, a new image is displayed. My question is how do I accomplish this in my .js file

```
var ImagePicker = {    
      init: function() {      
    imagePic = document.getElementById('pic');        
    imageTabsDiv = document.getElementById('imageTabs');        
    imageTabList = imageTabsDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');        
    for(var i =0; i <imageTabList.length; i++) {        
      imageTabList[i].onclick = imageTabList.imageTabClick           
      function imageTabClick() {          
        imagePath = this.getAttribute('longdesc');            
        imagePath.src = imagePic;          
      };        
    };      
  randomIndex = imageTabList[randomPics];      
  randomIndex = imageTabsDiv.getAttribute('longdesc');      
  randomIndex.src = imagePic;      
  randomPics: function() {      
    return Math.floor(Math.random() + 1);      
  };      
  };    
};    
Core.start(ImagePicker);
```

Code I am referencing from the HTML file...

```
<div id="primaryPic">
    <img src="images/pics/primaryPic.png" id="pic" alt="Primary Content Picture">
    
    <div id="imageTabs">
        <img src="images/pics/imageTab01.png" id="imageTab01" alt="imageTab01" longdesc="images/pics/bavLine.png"><br>
        <img src="images/pics/imageTab02.png" id="imageTab02" alt="imageTab02" longdesc="images/pics/frenchBugler.png"><br>
        <img src="images/pics/imageTab03.png" id="imageTab03" alt="imageTab03" longdesc="images/pics/Gendarme_a_Cheval_1870.png"><br>
        <img src="images/pics/imageTab04.png" id="imageTab04" alt="imageTab04" longdesc="images/pics/primaryPic.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to reference the `longdesc` attribute to change the pic every time the page is reloaded.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how do I use a random number generator to use on my NodeList that will enable me to randomly display a picture from a set of pics on my webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an image at random from `imageTabList`, you can do this:

```
var randomImg = imageTabList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageTabList.length)];
```

---

To get a random `longDesc` attribute each time you load the page, you can use this code:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("imageTabs").document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var randomImg = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)]
var randomLong = randomImg.getAttribute("longdesc");
```

FYI, you should be using `data-longdesc="xxxx"` at the attribute for HTML5 compatibility.

---

Here's an explanation:

```
Math.random()
```

creates a random floating point number between `0` and `1` (including `0`, not including `1`) such as `0.4857462391`.

```
Math.random() * imageTabList.length
```

creates a random floating point number between `0` and `imageTabList.length` (including `0`, not including `imageTabList.length` such as `8.239824379`.

To make that value an integer (for an array index), we call `Math.floor()` on it as in:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * imageTabList.length)
```

Now you have a random integer between 0 and imageTablList.length - 1 that you can use to grab a random item from that NodeList.

---

If you need any further help, please show your HTML as it isn't quite clear from your code what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the HTML portion I am trying to reference

Comment: @user2993994 - See the 2nd block of code I've added to my answer.  I don't know what you're trying to do with the random longDesc value once you get it, but that block of code shows you how to get a random one.

Comment: I got it I had to think for a little bit I fix my code. In the init method I used randomImg = imageTabList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageTabList.length)].getAttribute('longdesc');
    
    imagePic.src = randomImg; this allows for a new picture to be loaded at random when the page is loaded.

Comment: @user2993994 - glad you got it working.  So do you realize that at StackOverflow, there is a procedure to follow with selecting a best answer when someone helps you get your question answered?  This provides reputation points to both you and the answerer.

Comment: didn't know that but I got it figured out. Thank you for letting me know how things work. Appreciate it.